Powershell not correctly formatting a POST Request
I'm trying to use Powershell to send a file to VirusTotal, but each time I try, the response is:

"400 Bad Request: argument file is missing".

When I debug the request it shows correctly according to the VT API Documentation, but for some reason it doesn't work.
Currently I'm trying to make the request with this code:
        $fileExtension = [System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($file).TrimStart('.')
        $Mime= Get-MimeType -Extension "$fileExtension"
        # Get the base64 encoded file contents
        $fileContentsBase64 = [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file))
        # Construct the data string
        $dataString = "data:$Mime;name=$(Split-Path -Leaf $file);base64,$fileContentsBase64"
        $headers=@{}
        $headers.Add("accept", "application/json")
        $headers.Add("x-apikey", "MY_API_KEY")
        $headers.Add("content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=---011000010111000001101001")
        Write-Host $dataString
        # Make a POST request to the API to submit the file for analysis
        $response = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://www.virustotal.com/api/v3/files" -Method POST -Headers $headers -Body @"
    -----011000010111000001101001
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name="file"

    $dataString
    -----011000010111000001101001--
"@

All the headers are OK, and the boundaries should be OK too, but it doesn't work as expected. I suspect it has something to do with the Body of the request but I don't know how to correctly format it.

What happens if you just upload the bytes of the file as the body instead of converting this to base64 and posting it as a string like you're doing now (since the API documentation also doesn't mention)

You are adding a file to a MIME (multipart) attachment.  Each Multipart starts with two dashes on a new line.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/aa563375(v=exchg.140).  The error indicates you are missing a parameter.  VT API says only required parameter is x-apikey which you have in the code.  It also says password is optional, but your server may require the password.  If file is larger than 32MB use /files/upload_url endpoint.

Have you tried Postman?  Usually a recommend trying with Postman which is more robust and will automatically add missing parameters.  Once you get Postman working you can then use the Postman Control Panel to get full request and then add missing parameters to your code.
